# После установки новой версии Python 3.8, при попытке воспользоваться PIP выдаёт ошибку. Что делать?

Tags: python, cmd, pip

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.prepare import RequirementPreparer
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions import (
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions.source import SourceDistribution
ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution' from 'pip._internal.distributions.source' (c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\source\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать опцию

> pip ... --no-cache-dir

видимо проблема в кэше, оставшемся от предыдущей версии. Если вы используете виртуальное окружение, то имеет смысл стереть старое и создать новое, используя новую версию питона